# How to prevent images from resetting ordered list numbering in asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am using asciidoctor to generate html. I have the following list:

```
. one
. two 
. three

image::mypic.png[]
. four
```

And when converted to html, it looks like this:

```
1. one
2. two 
3. three
<my picture>
1. four
```

In html, I would like to see:

```
1. one
2. two 
3. three
<my picture>
4. four
```

I do not want to reset the counter manually after inserting an image, because i have a hundreds of similar situations.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Inspired by the asciidoctor documentation (section [Complex List Content](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#complex-list-content)) you can add a `+` instead of a blank line before your image block.

```
. one
. two 
. three
+
image::mypict.png[]
. four
```